# Parallelize a bash script and wait for each loop to finish

Tags: r, bash, parallel-processing

I'm trying to write a script, that we call pippo.R. pippo.R aim, is to run another script (for.sh) in a for loop with a parallelization using two values :
nPerm= total number of times the script has to be run
permAtTime= number of script that can run at the same time.
A very important thing to do, is to wait for each loop to be concluded, thats why I added a file in which all the PID are stored and then I use the wait function to wait for each of them. The main problem of this script is the following error :

```
./wait.sh: line 2: wait: pid 836844 is not a child of this shell
```

For reproducibility sake you can put in a folder the following files :
pippo.R

```
nPerm=10
permAtTime=2
cycles=nPerm/permAtTime
for(i in 1:cycles){
  d=1
  system(paste("./for.sh ", i," ",permAtTime,sep=""))
}
```

for.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
for X in $(seq $1)
do
 nohup ./script.sh $(($X +($2 -1)*$1 )) &
 echo $! >> ./save_pid.txt
done
./wait.sh
```

wait.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
while read p; do wait $p; done < ./save_pid.txt
```

Running Rscript pippo.R you will have the explained error. I know that there is the parallel function that can help me in this but for several reasons i cannot use that package.
Thanks

Comment: `wait.sh` doesn't work because the process running `for.sh` is forked to run `wait.sh` in a child process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to keep track of PIDs, because if you call `wait` without any argument, the script will wait for all the child processes to finish.

```sh
#!/bin/bash
for X in $(seq $1)
do
 nohup ./script.sh $(($X +($2 -1)*$1 )) &
done
wait
```